# Is there any way to audit , with hibernate-envers, an entity having an @Embedded in its EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have an entity BlocRecord having a composite code BlocRecordId, and in its composite code there is an @Embedded (relation code ManyToOne) pointing to another entiy Record and want to Audit the entity BlocRecord.

The entity BlocRecord

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "blocRecord")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@Audited
public class BlocRecord {

    @EmbeddedId

    private BlocRecordId blocRecordId = new BlocRecordId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "record_identifier_", referencedColumnName = "identifier_", unique = false, nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "record_recordType_", referencedColumnName = "recordType_", unique = false, nullable = false)})
    @MapsId("record")
    private Record record;

...

}
```

The id class BlocRecordID

```
@Embeddable
public class BlocRecordId implements Serializable {


    @Embedded
    private RecordId record;

    @Column(name = "source_")
    String source ;

    @Column(name = "messageType_")
    String messageType ;
```

The entity Record

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "records")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@Audited
public class Record {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RecordId recordId = new RecordId();


    @OneToMany(targetEntity = BlocRecord.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "record")
    private Set<BlocRecord> blocRecord = new java.util.HashSet<>();

...
}
```

The idClass of the entity Record

```
@Embeddable
public class RecordId implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "identifier_")
    String identifier ;

    @Column(name = "recordType_")
    String recordType ;

}
```

Hibernate-envers fails when trying to generate the metadata of the field record in the embeddable BlocRecordId, the The flowing exception is thrown

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addIdProperties(IdMetadataGenerator.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addId(IdMetadataGenerator.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:179)
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, Envers does not support the idea of nesting an embeddable inside an embeddable when we map the identifier columns like your example illustrates.  The only valid mappings that Envers presently does support is if the attribute in the embeddable is a `@ManyToOne` or a `@Basic` type.

You can work around this problem but it involves being a bit more explicit and not using `RecordId`.  What I mean is rewrite `BlocRecordId` to be the following:

```
@Embeddable
public class BlocRecordId implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "identifier_")
  String identifier;

  @Column(name = "recordType_")
  String recordType;

  @Column(name = "source_")
  String source;

  @Column(name = "messageType_")
  String messageType;

  @Transient
  private RecordId recordId;

  /** Helper method to assign the values from an existing RecordId */
  public void setRecordId(RecordId recordId) {
    this.identifier = recordId.getIdentifier();
    this.recordType = recordId.getRecordType();
  }

  /** Helper method to get the RecordId, caching it to avoid multiple allocations */
  public RecordId getRecordId() {
    if ( recordId == null ) {
      this.recordId = new RecordId( identifier, recordType );
    }
    return this.recordId;
  }
}
```

I agree this is less than ideal but it does at least work around the current limitation of the code.  I have gone added and added [HHH-13361](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13361) as an open issue to support this.  You're welcomed to contribute if you wish or I'll work in getting this supported for Envers 6.0.